# Is it possible for bash completion to cycle through the alternatives?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When using bash completion and an a number of characters have been entered, tabbing ceases to work when the prefix you have typed is matched by more than one of the possibilities.

Is there a way to cycle through the alternatives of the prefix you have entered?

Comment: If using another shell is an option, I believe both `fish` and `zsh` do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bind the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to the [`menu-complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-menu_002dcomplete-_0028_0029) command instead of the default `complete`. Put the following line in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind '"\C-i": menu-complete'
```

or the following line in your `~/.inputrc` (this will apply to all programs that use the readline library, not just bash):

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

Answer (score 6):

In bash 4.1 and later you can also use `menu-complete-backward` to cycle through completions backwards. I have this in my `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\es": menu-complete-backward
"\et": menu-complete
```