# Undo tab expansion?

Tags: bash, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

In bash, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> invokes the [programmable completion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) feature and either (a) expands to a unique path or command matching what's typed or (b) a list of possible options.

Is it possible to undo the *entire expansion* made by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Example:

1. My current command is `ls application/views/`.
2. There are two possible expansions on that command: `helpers/` and `scripts/`.
3. I type <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, which expands to `helpers/`.
4. I realize I *meant the other one* `scripts`.
5. Now I have to delete the entire expansion "helpers/".

I usually just backspace over the entire path (`helpers/` in this case), because I find striking readline undo <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> tedious.  What I'd like is a single key sequence that deletes the full match of the expansion, regardless of any characters I initially typed and any spaces or slashes added to the end.

---

Running list of key sequences suggested by comments or my own read of the [GNU reference](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_7.html#SEC55). *None of these accomplish the goal*:

- <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> -- Moves back to the previous `/` or , but doesn't delete.
- <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> -- Deletes one character, not the entire word.
- <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> -- Moves back one character without deleting.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> -- Deletes the entire path, not just the expansion. So in my example, after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, bash expands that to `ls application/views/helpers`, then when I press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, bash deletes `application/views/helpers`.

If relevant, I'm using the vi editing mode on a Gentoo Linux box. I've checked my configuration and I've not remapped any characters.

Comment: You can delete back one word with `M-b` (<alt>+b).

Comment: @jordanm That just jumps my cursor back, not deleting. Thoughts?

Comment: Words are usually deleted via `<ctl>W`

Comment: @schily That just blasts the entire path, not the expanded component.

Comment: @bishop sorry, that should be `M-<backspace>`. `M-b` is move back one word. `M-d` is delete one word forward.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible for bash completion to cycle through the alternatives](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146690/is-it-possible-for-bash-completion-to-cycle-through-the-alternatives)

Comment: @jordanm Sadly, M-backspace just moves my cursor back one character, not one work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're giving the keystrokes, but not the *readline bindings*, this can explain differences in observed behaviour (try `bind -p`).

The only way I can think of to do *exactly* what you ask is to use a custom completion function that saves the buffer state, and a separate key binding which invokes a companion shell function to restore it.

In addition to @Mark Plotnick's excellent suggestion to use `menu-complete`, other readline/bash options are:

- `shell-backward-kill-word` this removes a "shell word" which in the case of an expanded file or path will be the complete file or path name
- `backward-kill-word` this removes a "readline word", which in the case of a file or path will be a file or directory name component, including the trailing `/`
- `undo` which undoes each change atomically, but this almost certainly requires several attempts to fully remove a complete expansion, this is almost certainly the function you have bound to to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> (bash default)
- `set-mark` and `kill-region` are lesser used readline features, `set-mark` marks the current cursor position, and `kill-region` deletes from the mark to the cursor. This requires you to invoke `set-mark` (default <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>) in advance so that you can later use `kill-region` to delete back to it (no default binding)
- `possible-completions` (bound to <kbd>meta</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd>) which lists the completions *without* modifying the command buffer

You could also write your own function to modify the input buffer, and bind it to a function (here's [one I made earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/837248/how-can-i-rename-move-a-file-by-simply-editing-its-path-in-a-shell)) but I don't see how that would be very much better than `backward-kill-word` in this case.

You can test bindings on the fly without using `.inputrc` using bash's `bind` command, e.g.:

```
bind "\C-o: backward-kill-word"
bind "\C-o: shell-backward-kill-word"
```

`backward-kill-word` is the best fit, default binding is <kbd>meta</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd>. `set-mark`/`kill-region` would be better, but I can't think of a neat way to automate the use of this though.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  `bind -p` showed that backward-kill-word was unbound. I rigged it up to my Shift+Tab with [`"\e[Z": backward-kill-word`](https://github.com/bishopb/bashworks/blob/master/dotfiles/inputrc) and now it does *exactly* what I want.

Comment: zsh's undo can actually undo a completion in one step!