# What does `bind '"\C-i": menu-complete'` do?

Tags: bash, readline

I would like to  fill out a command which expects a file argument, by alternating the files in the current directory. So I followed [Gilles' reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146716/674)

> Bind the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to the
>   [`menu-complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-menu_002dcomplete-_0028_0029)
>   command instead of the default `complete`. Put the following line in
>   your `~/.bashrc`:
>
> ```
> bind '"\C-i": menu-complete'
> ```

Does `"\C-i"` represent the  <kbd>Tab</kbd> key? Where is this specified? I thought `"\C-i"` representing `Ctrl-i`.

After I run the command `bind '"\C-i": menu-complete'`,    the  <kbd>Tab</kbd> key doesn't seem to work for any purpose (including any kind of auto completion) in bash.
Do I miss understand the purpose of the command?

How can I undo the command, i.e. make the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key work for the default style of auto completion again? For recovery, I have run the following commands, some by accident, and none of them seem to work for recovery:

```
bind -u 'menu-complete'
bind -u 'complete'
bind '"TAB": complete'
bind '"\TAB": complete'
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd> is in every way *identical* to <kbd>Tab</kbd> (it's what the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key generates). I tried following Gilles' suggestion and I can still tab complete filenames etc., though it behaves slightly different now (each press on <kbd>Tab</kbd> gives the next suggested completion).

To reset it to the default, use

```
bind '"\C-i": complete'
```

Comment: Thanks. (1) Where is "Ctrl+i is in every way identical to Tab" specified? (2) `bind '"\C-i": complete'` doesn't  recover the default setting

Comment: @Tim A `Tab` character is ASCII code 9, this is what `Ctrl+i` generates. `Ctrl+j` generates a character with ASCII code 10 (linefeed, or the same as `Enter`). `Ctrl+a` generates a character with code 1.  `i` happens to be the 9th character of the alphabet, which is why `Ctrl+i` generates this character.  Why this is so seems to be outside the scope of this question.