# Ubuntu tab autocompletion like PowerShell

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

For me PowerShell tab auto-completion is much better than my Terminal console in Linux. Is there a way to configure this?

For example

```
usr@Ubuntu:~/esp/esp-idf$ ls -ahl
drwxrwxr-x 16 usr usr 4.0K Sep 11 19:57 examples
-rw-rw-r--  1 usr usr 2.1K Sep 11 19:57 export.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 usr usr 2.5K Sep 11 19:57 export.fish
-rw-rw-r--  1 usr usr 2.8K Sep 11 19:57 export.ps1
-rw-rw-r--  1 usr usr 4.9K Sep 11 19:57 export.sh

usr@Ubuntu:~/esp/esp-idf$ cd *port*       <tab> -->
usr@Ubuntu:~/esp/esp-idf$ cd export.bat   <tab> -->
usr@Ubuntu:~/esp/esp-idf$ cd export.fish
```

In powershell I can do `cd ex <tab>` and it will autocomplete with the first one of the list, then I can press `<tab>` agan and it will change it to the second of the list. I can also do `cd *ex*sh` and it will find something that matches that.
It can go even further and do `cd es*/es*/ex*.sh <tab>` and it will auto-complete to `cd esp/esp-idf/export.sh`

My memory is really bad and I don't remember the exact case sensitive name of all directories, but I have an idea of what they contain, so for me that autocompletion is really fast and useful

Comment: It's not the same but do you know about using two tabs in succession?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for bash completion to cycle through the alternatives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146690/is-it-possible-for-bash-completion-to-cycle-through-the-alternatives)

Comment: Thanks @roaima - that answer is already a great improvement! :)

Comment: You might also want to look into other shells. I believe both `fish` and `zsh` do what you want out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @terdon, I will give them a try